# SVG - Background size not resizing SVG image, instead its changing it's position

Tags: css, svg, background-size

I am trying to use the background size property to scale my background image like this

```
.myDiv
  background-image url('background-fill.svg')  
  background-repeat no-repeat
  background-size 100% 336px
```

But changing the 336px does not rescale the image's height, instead the image is always proportional (adding to 336px moves the image down, and subtracting from 336px moves the image up, it does not change the size of the image)

For example, if I do

```
  background-size 100% 536px
```

The image moves lower, and displays the same size as before

If I change for a png, or a jpg, it works as expected

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: In addition to providing your HTML and CSS per the previous comment, can you provide the SVG/XML too? At the very least, we'll need to see what your SVG has set for width, height, viewBox, and preserveAspectRatio in the SVG file itself. Those can have an effect on how the SVG is resized/scaled.

Comment: @HBlackorby I found the problem , I posted it as an answer to my own question. Needed to set preserveAspectRatio="none" to my svg. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, I had to set

```
preserveAspectRatio="none"
```

in my .svg, inside the svg tag